# Point() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (2 given)

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I'm trying to run an example [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#guard), but get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: Point() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (2 given)
```

Can someone explain what I doing wrong here?

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

x, y = 5 ,5
point = Point(x, y)
match point:
    case Point(x, y) if x == y:
        print(f"Y=X at {x}")
    case Point(x, y):
        print(f"Not on the diagonal")
```

Comment: Please post your complete error message as well.

Comment: my bad, I thought the `if` could be causing an issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to define `__match_args__` in your class. As pointed at [in this section](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#patterns-with-positional-parameters) of the "What's new in 3.10" page:

> You can use positional parameters with some builtin classes that
> provide an ordering for their attributes (e.g. dataclasses). You can
> also define a specific position for attributes in patterns by setting
> the `__match_args__` special attribute in your classes. If it’s set to
> (“x”, “y”), the following patterns are all equivalent (and all bind
> the y attribute to the var variable):
>
> ```
> Point(1, var) 
> Point(1, y=var) 
> Point(x=1, y=var) 
> Point(y=var, x=1)
> ```

So your class will need to look as follows:

```
class Point:                                                                                            
    __match_args__ = ("x", "y")                                                                         
    def __init__(self, x, y):                                                                           
        self.x = x                                                                                      
        self.y = y
```

Alternatively, you could change your match structure to the following:

```
match point:                                                                                            
    case Point(x=x, y=y) if x == y:                                                                       
        print(f"Y=X at {x}")                                                                            
    case Point(x=x, y=y):                                                                                   
        print(f"Not on the diagonal")
```

(Note that you don't need a both: a class with `__match_args__` defined, does not need to have its arguments specified in the match-case statements.)

For full details, I'll refer readers to [PEP 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/), which is the specification for structural pattern matching. The details on this particular point are in the section [Class Patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#class-patterns).

For a better introduction or tutorial, don't use the "What's New" documentation, as it tends to provide an overview, but may skip over some things. Instead, use [PEP 636 -- Structural Pattern Matching: Tutorial](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/), or the language reference on [match statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement) for more details.

---

It is mentioned in the quoted text that a dataclass will already have an ordering, and in your example, a dataclass also works fine:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass                                                                       
                                                                                                        
@dataclass                                                                                              
class Point:                                                                                            
    x: int                                                                                              
    y: int                                                                                              
                                                                                                        
x, y = 5, 5                                                                                             
point = Point(x, y)                                                                                     
                                                                                                        
match point:                                                                                            
    case Point(x, y) if x == y:                                                                         
        print(f"Y=X at {x}")                                                                            
    case Point(x, y):                                                                                   
        print(f"Not on the diagonal")
```

Comment: Good find. The documentation should have included a better example for `Point` when position-matching params. In effect, a copy-paste from the examples for `__match_args__` would fail, like it has for the OP.

Comment: @aneroid True, but I think better documentation right now is to be found in the [PEP 636 -- Structural Pattern Matching: Tutorial](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/), or the language reference on [match statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement). The "What's New" tends to provide just a quick overview, so it will  skip some things.

Comment: Fair enough. But I think that's confusing for people referring to the docs, because now they'd have to read the PEP and track it against which Python version a feature belongs to, if it changes in the future. Better for the docs to have just a one-liner and then "go read PEP 636". So the relevant info is one place. Your answer is still the right one, of course :-)