# Why doesn't fractions.Fraction support positional sub-patterns?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-fractions

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
match lst:
  case list((1, 2, 3)):
    print(2)
```

gives `2` as output, but,

```
from fractions import Fraction

frctn = Fraction(1, 2)

match frctn:
  case Fraction(1, 2):
    print(1)
```

gives,

```
TypeError: Fraction() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (2 given)
```

any specific reasoning for allowing positional sub-patterns for some types while not allowing them for some types?

Comment: I would try named sub-patterns: `Fraction(numerator=1, denominator=2)`. I'm very new to pattern matching, but my guess would be whether positional or named subpatterns are accepted depends on the `__init__()` declaration of the class.

Comment: Related (maybe a dupe?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627609/point-accepts-0-positional-sub-patterns-2-given

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#matching-positional-attributes the logic seems to be that most classes "don’t have a natural ordering of their attributes" - the pattern match _isn't creating an instance_, so it is not using the order of args to `__init__` method.  I guess `list` allows it because it takes a single arg, also because matching sequences is important part of pattern matching functionality https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#matching-sequences

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, my comment about `__init__()` was incorrect. I posted an update as an actual answer. Also, since sequences have a natural ordering (because they are sequences), it makes sense to match elements by position.

Answer (score 2):

Positional subpatterns in a class are declared using the `__match_args__` magic attribute. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#patterns-with-positional-parameters) for details. It appears that `Fraction` doesn't declare this attribute, so you must use named subpatterns instead:

```
Fraction(numerator=1, denominator=2)
```

See [Point() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627609/point-accepts-0-positional-sub-patterns-2-given)